# How to select multiple blockquotes with sublime text and remove unecessary tags inside?

Tags: sublimetext2, notepad++

I have a huge XML file with multiple blockquotes code sections like this:

```
<blockquote>lorem Lorem Ipsum<i> is simply dummy text</i> of the printing and typesetting industry. "Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text" ever since the <b>1500s</b>, when an unknown printer <i>took a galley</i> of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen booki>
```

I need to select all the blockquote and content inside blockquote tags in order to remove and clean unnecessary tags like:

```
<i>, <em>, </em>, </p>, </i>, <b>, </b>, <strong>, </strong> and " inside the text.
```

End results:

```
<blockquote>lorem Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book</blockquote>
```

Comment: so you want to select all text between two `<blockquote>` tags, remove all tags and quote marks in the selection, and replace back just the plain text?

Comment: Please [show what did you try so far](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182266/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) to solve the problem.